# Use reverse_iterator with type erasure

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, reverse-iterator, boost-type-erasure

I have a class which contains and manages a series of objects. To avoid leaking how these objects are stored while allowing to iterate through them, I decided to use type erasure using `boost::any_iterator`.

```
 using my_erased_type_iterator = boost::range_detail::any_iterator<
    MyClass,
    boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag,
    MyClass&, 
    std::ptrdiff_t>;
```

I defined a function `Begin()` and `End()` in `MyClass`, which simply returns the container's `begin()` and `end()` function as a `my_erased_type_iterator`. It works exactly as I want to, and nobody outside of `MyClass` knows I'm using a vector to store the objects nor do they have access to the container aside from the functions I expose in `Myclass`'s interface.

Now, for a number of reasons, I need to reverse-iterate through the objects. I also need to know the next element after a reverse iterator (akin to calling `std::next()` on a normal iterator, which is already not so trivial for reverse iterators) and I might also need to call functions like `erase()` on that reverse iterator.

So for my question: is there an elegant way to use type-erasure along with reverse iterators (and the const version of both forward and reverse) ? Should I use forward type-erased iterators and iterate backward instead? It crossed my mind that I might be tackling this problem the wrong way, so I'm open to any suggestions or to clarify my questions if needed.

Comment: You do understand that your choice has a performance cost, and iterator invalidation rules (which are pretty unique to each container) leak what container you are using anyhow?  (When your iterators are invalid is part of your interface)

Comment: Ah. I now see the request relating to `erase()` - I missed it due to all the "type erasure". You cannot use `erase` with "baked" iterators, because there is no (unhacky) way get back at the underlying iterators. /cc @Yakk

Comment: @sehe sigh, they didn't include the equivalent of `std::function::target<T>()`?  Slackers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `any_iterator` is an implementation detail.

I'll answer your direct question first, then show the approach with `any_range<>` as intended by the public API of Boost Range.

#### 1. `make_reverse_iterator`

You can simply use the `make_reverse_iterator` facility from

- standard c++14 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_reverse_iterator
- boost http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/iterator/doc/reverse_iterator.html

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1305ad2374c7f8c5)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/any_range.hpp>

struct MyClass {
    int i;
};

using my_erased_type_iterator = boost::range_detail::any_iterator<
    MyClass,
    boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag,
    MyClass&, 
    std::ptrdiff_t>;

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    using namespace boost;
    std::vector<MyClass> const v { {1}, {2}, {3}, {4} };

    for (auto& mc : make_iterator_range(
                make_reverse_iterator(v.end()),
                make_reverse_iterator(v.begin())))
    {
        std::cout << mc.i << " ";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
4 3 2 1
```

---

#### 2. `reversed` range adaptor:

Alternatively, you can go full range-style and use `any_range<>`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/282ca96c04c154d8)</kbd>**

```
int main() {
    std::vector<MyClass> const v { {1}, {2}, {3}, {4} };

    boost::any_range_type_generator<decltype(v)>::type x = reverse(v);

    for (my_erased_type_const_iterator f = boost::begin(x), l = boost::end(x); f!=l; ++f) {
        std::cout << f->i << " ";
    }

}
```

Comment: Added caveat about library implementation details, and a cleaner `any_range<>` version.

Comment: Does not support erase?

Comment: @Yakk What do you mean? In my samples, they're const iterators, and bidirectional / random depending on the use. Care to clarify?

Comment: The OP wants to erase elements using the reverse iterators as where the erase should go (exact details are fuzzy).

Comment: "as where the erase should go" - I'm at a loss what your sentence means, sorry

Comment: Suppose I have a reverse iterator bob.  Suppose I erase using bob as where I want to erase.  Does it erase `std::prev(bob.base())`?  What does the erase function return?  Those are guesses: OP says she wants to erase using reverse iterators.  Details of what exactly that means are fuzzy.

Comment: The problem is `bob.base()` was erased so it doesn't even compile. @Yakk (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/960dfa749ad53932). I read the question as being about erased iterators more than just reversed iterators. The reversed part is pretty pedestrian (and the OP can work out the semantics he needs)

Answer (score 1):

Simply reverse the type erased iterators.

This exposes `.base()`, which means erasing is almost as easy as erasing the type erased forward ones.

As an aside, your design has performance costs for (in my experience) marginal benefit.  The iterafor invalidadion rules of the underlying container still apply, so the user of your class has to know what the underlying container is anyhow! (Or, know so much they might as well).  Swappimng out the container will not provide sufficiently similar behaviour, so your container is locked in despite your reasonably costly attempt to hide it.

Comment: Since i'm still in the early stage of developing my program, I wanted to avoid "binding" classes together. Type erasure seemed like a good idea for doing just that. It might go out of the window later when I'll have metrics and a profiler showing me that the performance cost is too great for the design benefits, but for now, I want to prioritize good design over performance.

Comment: @user1784377 Sure, except there is very rarely a reason to use anything besides a `vector` for a non-associative container.  This erasure might let you store something else alongside what you want to expose in the same vector later on. But one of the rules you should remember is "you probably won't need it": writing a bunch of (possibly costly) abstraction early on might solve some problem in a year, but more likely you won't need that abstraction. The project will be dead, possibly killed by over-abstraction, or the abstraction was not needed.

Comment: I do know about "you probably won't need it" and I tend to avoid coding stuff until I really need it, but I guess it also applies to design and abstraction. Although I do hope the project will still be around in a year and I'm not looking forward to adding that abstraction later, I think you might be right and getting rid of that extra-abstraction right now might simplify and accelerate the development as a whole.